# How to verify domain with Mailgun PHP library?

Tags: php, mailgun

How can I verify the domain using the Mailgun PHP library and get the current used DNS records?

The verification method exists in the [API Documentation](http://mailgun-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-domains.html#domains), but I can not find one in the [PHP library](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php).

I need this method:

`PUT /domains/<domain>/verify`

Comment: you make a curl request.

Comment: @FMashiro, yes I can, but why method not exists in the API?

Comment: according to the docs, you can call `/domains/<domain>` (Replace `<domain>` with the domain you're looking for). It's possible, all you need to do is call the api url with `/domains/example.com` at the end of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add PR for repository, and now for verify domain we can use:

```
$mailgun = Mailgun::create('key-example');
$mailgun->domains()->verify('example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can get the DNS records by doing this:

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('key-example');
$dns = $mg->domains()->show('example.com')->getInboundDNSRecords();

foreach ($dns as $record) {
  echo $record->getType();
}
```

Comment: When I call ```->show```, domain verification not starting, I need ```PUT /domains/<domain>/verify``` from the API.

Comment: @MaximZasorin You should use a CURL call for that, you know how to use it?